# C# Download Partial Video Live Stream

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I want to download 10 seconds video from live streaming but it has no file output when I do `cts.Cancel()`.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();;
...
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResult = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://.....video.flv", cts.Token);
var resultStream = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var fileStream = File.Create(saveDir);
resultStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Comment: You might want to use the `GetStreamAsync()` method, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-8.0

Comment: By default, `GetAsync()` buffers the entire response into memory before returning. You're not even making it to the `ReadAsStreamAsync()`. Pass `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to `GetAsync()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution I have to add `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to `GetAsync` and add `cts.Token` to `CopyToAsync`

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(videoUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo, 81920, cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```